# sqlite3 transactions and the exec call

Tags: c++, database, sqlite

I have an entire set of data i want to insert into a table.  I am trying to have it insert/update everything OR rollback.  I was going to do it in a transaction, but i wasnt sure if the *sql_exec()* command did the same thing.

My goal was to iterate through the list.
Select from each iteration based on the Primary Key.

```
If result was found:
  append update to string;
else
  append insert to string;
```

Then after iterating through the loop, i would have a giant string and say:

*sql_exec(string);
sql_close(db);*

Is that how i should do it?  I was going to do it on each iteration of the loop, but i didnt think a global rollback if there was an error.

Comment: I would `sqlite3_exec()` the `BEGIN`, then individually execute each update.  You can then commit or rollback, depending upon however you measure "success".

Comment: @Chad Why is that a comment instead of an answer?

Comment: @BrianCampbell Maybe it's because he's on a cell phone and doesn't have time to put in clear code, as of yet.  I'm wondering if he meant 'the `BEGIN`' or 'then `BEGIN`'....

Comment: @Wolfpack'08 I'm pretty sure he meant "the `BEGIN`", as in "run `sqlite3_exec()` on the `BEGIN` statement". I've expanded on his comment, and several other issues this raises, in an answer.

Comment: Thanks, Brian.  I really like your answers.

Comment: I just didn't have time to type up a good extensive answer.  @BrianCampbell+1 for yours which was exactly what I would have said given the time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you should not append everything into a giant string. If you do, you will need to allocate a whole bunch of memory as you are going, and it will be harder to create good error messages for each individual statement, as you will just get a single error for the entire string. Why spend all of that effort, constructing one big string when SQLite is just going to have to parse it back down into its individual statements again?

Instead, as @Chad suggests, you should just use `sqlite3_exec()` on a `BEGIN` statement, which will begin a transaction. Then `sqlite3_exec()` each statement in turn, and finally `sqlite3_exec()` a `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK` depending on how everything goes. The `BEGIN` statement will start a transaction, and all of the statements executed after that will be within that transaction, and so committed or rolled back together. That's what the "A" in [ACID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) stands for; Atomic, as all of the statements in the transaction will be committed or rolled back as if they were a single atomic operation.

Furthermore, you probably shouldn't use `sqlite3_exec()` if some of the data varies within each statement, such as being read from a file. If you do, a mistake could easily leave you with an [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) bug. For instance, if you construct your query by appending strings, and you have strings like `char *str = "it's a string"` to insert, if you don't quote it properly, your statement could come out like `INSERT INTO table VALUES ('it's a string');`, which will be an error. Or if someone malicious could write data into this file, then they could cause you to execute any SQL statement they want ([imagine](http://xkcd.com/327/) if the string were `"'); DROP TABLE my_important_table; --"`). You may think that no one malicious is going to provide input, but you can still have accidental problems, if someone puts a character that confuses the SQL parser into a string.

Instead, you should use [`sqlite3_prepare_v2()`](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/prepare.html) and [`sqlite3_bind_...()`](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html) (where `...` is the type, like `int` or `double` or `text`). In order to do this, you use a statement like `char *query = "INSERT INTO table VALUES (?)"`, where you substitute a `?` for where you want your parameter to go, prepare it using `sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, query, -1, &stmt, NULL)`, bind the parameter using `sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, str, -1, SQLITE_STATIC)`, then execute the statement with [`sqlite3_step(stmt)`](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/step.html). If the statement returns any data, you will get `SQLITE_ROW`, and can access the data using the various [`sqlite3_columne_...()`](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/column_blob.html) functions. Be sure to read the documentation carefully; some of the example parameters I gave may need to change depending on how you use this.

Yes, this is a bit more of a pain than calling `sqlite3_exec()`, but if your query has any data loaded from external sources (files, user input), this is the only way to do it correctly. `sqlite3_exec()` is fine to call if the entire text of the query is contained within your source, such as the `BEGIN` and `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK` statements, or pre-written queries with no parts coming from outside of your program, you just need prepare/bind if there's any chance that an unexpected string could get in.

Finally, you don't need to query whether something is in the database already, and then insert or update it. You can do a `INSERT OR REPLACE` query, which will either insert a record, or replace one with a matching primary key, which is the equivalent of selecting and then doing an `INSERT` or an `UPDATE`, but much quicker and simpler. See the [`INSERT`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html) and ["on conflict"](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html) documentation for more details.

Comment: It's possible that a part of the answer is missing because it seems the asker is simply trying to set up an `if($query = !empty){INSTERT} else {UPDATE}` situation (i.e., in php; however, the tag indicates c++).  In any event, it likely requires a programming or scripting language.

Comment: insert or replace would do the job of my if statement so i dont have to build language specific tools.   Thanks for the information Brian.